# Combine BuildType and Flavor resources

Tags: android, gradle

I have 2 versions of app: paid-app and free-app. I use gradle and Android Studio. 
I have next folder structure:
`src` folder, and inside it 3 folders: `main`, `paidapp`, `freeapp` - where paidapp and freeapp are flavors. 
My configs:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    freeapp {
    }
    paidapp {
        applicationId 'com.company.paidapp'
    }
}
```

What I want: have on my phone 4 apps:

```
package com.company.dev, name "dev freeapp"
package com.company.paidapp.dev, name "dev paidapp"
package com.company, name "freeapp"
package com.company.paidapp, name "paidapp"
```

package is ok, gradle manage it automatically, **but how to create different names for app?**

App name located in `strings.xml` 
in `src/paidapp/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="appName">dev paidapp</string>
```

in `src/freeapp/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="appName">dev freeapp</string>
```

I looked there - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

The priority order is the following:
BuildType -> Flavor -> main -> Dependencies.

So I can chose or string from BuildType or from Flavor, but how to combine BuildType and Flavor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a folder `src/freeappRelease/res/values/` and add your very specific strings in this folder.

Comment: Yes, after you answer I reread documentation and have founded this nuance - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies